# What is the difference between autoindent and smartindent in vimrc?

Tags: indentation

I read the wiki entry on [vim source code indentation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code)

I still can't understand the difference between `autoindent` and `smartindent`

It seems they do the same thing, copy the indentation level to next line when you press `enter`.

Comment: The wiki is very close to useless. Read `:help autoindent` and `:help smartindent`.

Comment: the wiki actually has a pretty decent explanation of your options: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code#Methods_for_automatic_indentation

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`autoindent` essentially tells vim to apply the indentation of the current line to the next (created by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> in *insert* mode or with <kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>o</kbd> in *normal* mode.

`smartindent` reacts to the syntax/style of the code you are editing (especially for C). When having it *on* you also should have `autoindent` *on*.

`:help autoindent` also mentions two alternative settings: `cindent` and `indentexpr`, both of which make vim ignore the value of `smartindent`.

Comment: The answer above is correct. The Only thing you need to do extra to enable this while using vim or in the .vimrc is to use `set` command in the beginning. i.e. `set autoindent`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se], @m33k! I turned your post into a comment, since it was clearly referring to this answer. Cheers!