# How can I change the indent size?

Tags: indentation

I just discovered I could indent and un-indent easily in Vi with : <kbd><<</kbd> and <kbd>>></kbd>

By default it adds a `tab` character. Now I'm wondering, could this be to a number of spaces via a configuration in my `.vimrc`? And how should I do it?

Comment: 1) `tabstop` is effectively how many columns of whitespace a `\t` character is worth. 2) `shiftwidth` is how many columns of whitespace a “level of indentation” is worth. The `>` action indents by 1 level. 3) `softtabstop` is how many columns of whitespace a `tab keypress` or a `backspace keypress` is worth. ... More on tab settings in vim in a medium article I wrote https://medium.com/@arisweedler/tab-settings-in-vim-1ea0863c5990

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Several settings controls the behavior:

First `set expandtab` allows to replace the tabs by white spaces characters [`:h 'expandtab'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27expandtab%27).

Then `set shiftwidth=4` makes the tabulations be 4 white spaces [`:h 'shiftwidth'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27shiftwidth%27).

You could also be interested by by [`:h 'tabstop'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27tabstop%27) which defines the number of spaces that a tab character in the file counts for.

As a bonus see [`:h 'smartindent'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27smartindent%27) and [`:h 'autoindent'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autoindent%27) which are pretty useful.

Answer (score 26):

In fact, aside from other answers, it is also possible to use `autoindent` (to automatically indent newlines) and [`smartindent`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/what-is-the-difference-between-autoindent-and-smartindent-in-vimrc) (which works with C-like braces languages less strictly than `cindent`). Then the `shiftwidth` I wanted was `2`.

I modified my `$HOME/.vimrc` like this:

```
:set shiftwidth=2
:set autoindent
:set smartindent
```

Comment: also
:set tabstop=2

Comment: I think it would be really helpful to add more explanations as to what the different lines do

Comment: @J.Chomel https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: @J.Chomel actually none of the other answers here explain what autoindent or smartindent do. I think that even if that was the case, either your answer is a comment, in which case it can exempt itself from explanation, or it's a full blown answer, in which case it should not be code only if it's not self-explanatory

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew, I guess you know more... Bravo

Comment: @J.Chomel I am just trying to make it easier for everyone to learn. Good job on editing your answer, I think it is way more helpful now

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

You can set `shiftwidth` to any number of spaces.
This works both in `vi` and  `vim`.

```
:set shiftwidth=2
```

Now, the width shifted for each `>>` and `<<` will be 2.

Answer (score 3):

1. press <kbd>esc</kbd> then `v` to get into visual mode
2. select the lines which you want to modify the indents
3. and then press `=`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This doesn't affect tabs vs spaces; it simply re-indents the lines. And visual mode is not strictly necessary, given that `=` is an operator.

Comment: +1 doing that changed the indent size of my existing code and that is what the title asks, so thanks. @D.BenKnoble the `=` worked as it should in visual mode, and in non visual mode is ignored in place of the `+` which adds a line above. Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
touch ~/.vimrc
echo "set ts=4 sw=4" >> ~/.vimrc
```

Shorthand for J.Chomel's answer.
`touch` will create the file .vimrc in your home directory if it doesn't exists yet
Next, append tabstop and shiftwidth with your preferences to the *.vimrc file*.

Comment: Note that it is considered a best practice to use options long name in your vimrc (i.e. `tabstop` and `shiftwidth`) it is usually more readable and since your don't need to type them that often in your config file there is not much gain to use short names.