# Indenting now add suspicious chars to my files when pasting

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste, indentation, putty

Following answer I got [there](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7977/6946) to allow <kbd>>></kbd> to indent, I edited my `.vimrc` to this:

```
:set shiftwidth=2
:set autoindent
:set smartindent
```

But now when I copy/paste (via putty), it indents incrementally, by inserting unwanted "tabs".

I copy

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << " Hello Vi and Vim!";
    return 0;
}
```

and when I paste in edit mode, it indent incrementally and it becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
    int main() {
            std::cout << " Hello Vi and Vim!";
                    return 0;
                        }
```

It won't happen if I remove my `.vimrc`. Does it ring any bells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, you should set the `paste` option to prevent indentation.

```
set paste
```

When you are done, you should then set `nopaste`.

What happens is that the pasted file is already indented but Vim try to indent it as well, the `paste` option prevent this.

You can also set a key to turn `paste` on and off with, e.g.:

```
set pastetoggle=<C-P>
```